# how can I split the first letter/unit from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTvpw.png)
hi guys, im learning to code and doing this problem.
my codes work fine with the problem. however, it only takes input of "1 + 1", which have spaces in between (exactly as the problem mentioned). I want to make it in a way that even if the input is "1+1", which is with no spaces, it will still work.
this is my code and i hope someone can point out the problem in my codes and teach me why is the problem existing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g8ru.png)

My thoughts on it is that i will use the split function with parameter, which will be .split(operator).
However, it then relates to a method which I can scan through the string input and find the operator, store it in a variable, then scan the input again to split it right on the operator. I dont know how to do this part. Of course, any other methods which may solve the above problem is fine too. I just want to try to perfect things up and not limited to what the question tells me to do.

code block:

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Expression: \n")
    result(user_input)

def result(x):
    num1, operator, num2 = x.split(" ")
    intnum1 = int(num1)
    intnum2 = int(num2)

    if operator == "+":
        result = intnum1 + intnum2
    elif operator == "-":
        result = intnum1 - intnum2
    elif operator == "*":
        result = intnum1 * intnum2
    elif operator == "/":
        result = intnum1 / intnum2
    else:
        print("Invalid operator")
        return

    print(f"{result:.1f}")

main()
```

I want to know how can I be able to make both "1 + 1" and "1+1" works.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i77317881/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sounds like you want tokenization. I'd tokenize by recognizing numbers as one or more digits, +-*/ as operators, and skipping spaces.

Comment: @Luatic What about 1.5*4.3 ?

Comment: @Codist oh, they want to support decimals? To me the phrasing of the question implied that they are only dealing with integer literals. Of course, for decimals, you'd have to extend number tokenization to recognize `\d+(\.\d+)?`. At that point you might want to start using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should not assume that you will need only the first number, what if someone enters `11+11`?

You can either first check if any of `+-\*` Is in string using `'+' in x` etc and then split by it getting 2 elements - first and second number

Or you can use regex with something like `(\d+)([\+\-\\\*])(\d+)` which after using `re.match` would give you 3 groups - number1, operation, number 2

You can also combine both of solutions under one regex with `(\d+) ?([\+\-\\\*]) ?(\d+)` which would also match cases like `1+ 1` and `1 +1`

Regex playground:
https://regexr.com/7lrea

Comment: `re.findall(r"(\S)", txt)` is an easier approach in this particular case

Comment: Not exactly as `\S` will match only a single character thus `11 + 11` will become `(1, 1, '+', 1, 1)`

Comment: Which is not the particular case the OP asked about.

Comment: You are right, but at the same, that is just one example and if we check the task that's attached in an image, there is no statement about single-digit numbers, they are just called integers, which means `11 + 11` is a possible equation. 
And I created my answer as a more generalizable solution and in that case your suggestion won't work, but it will in OPs provided sample.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to capture everything either side of the known operators. In this way you can easily handle both integer and float values.

Something like this:

```
import re
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

opmap = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul, "/": truediv}

while value := input("Expression: "):
    try:
        x, o, y = re.findall(r"^(.*)([+|\-|\*|/])(.*)$", value)[0]
        print(opmap[o](float(x), float(y)))
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid operator")
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        print("Malformed expression")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Can't divide by zero")
```

EDIT: Without any utility module imports (only suitable for integer values):

```
while value := input("Expression: "):
    try:
        for i, c in enumerate(value):
            if not c.isdecimal():
                x = int(value[:i])
                y = int(value[i + 1 :])
                match c:
                    case "+":
                        print(x + y)
                    case "-":
                        print(x - y)
                    case "*":
                        print(x * y)
                    case "/":
                        print(x / y)
                    case _:
                        print("Unrecognised operator")
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except Exception:
        print("Invalid expression")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice! However I am currently a very new self taught coder, I am trying to stick with what the course has taught which doesnt include any of the import of libraries/package yet. But I will definitely look it up soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a very barebones solution

```py
string = "123*143"
delimiters = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
out = ""
for delimiter in delimiters:
    # try to split the string by the delimiter
    # of the current loop iteration e.g. "*" sign
    subs = string.split(delimiter)
    # if splitting for the current delimiter e.g. * was successfull,
    # then in this usecase the array of substrings contains 2 elements
    if len(subs) == 2:
        # here the string is being rebuilt in the format you were
        # using in your initial question.
        # e.g. "123 * 143"
        # the first "" is only there for readability, to make sure that
        # the + operator for strings is being used to concatenate the
        # elements as string called out, and not the numeral + which
        # is used to add numbers together.
        # And also to keep it simple. I wanted to avoid the use
        # of join() or Literal String Interpolation,
        # as you were using it later on f"{result:.1f}") 
        out = "" + subs[0] + " " + delimiter +" "+ subs[1]
    

result = out.split()
 
print(result)
# which will print this as output
# ['123', '*', '143']
```

Comment: just tried this out and it works very well! but can you please explain this part?
{
for delimiter in delimiters:
    subs = string.split(delimiter)
    if len(subs) == 2:
        out = "" + subs[0] + " " + delimiter +" "+ subs[1]
}
i dont really get how is this part functioning

Comment: nice, yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have figured out a way to do it! Please check if there's anything that I can simplify (without libraries or packages cause I am really new haha).

```
def main():
    user_input = input("Expression: \n")
    result(user_input)

def result(x):
    y = x.lstrip("0123456789")
    z = y.rstrip("0123456789")
    operator = z.strip()
    num1, num2 = x.split(operator)
    intnum1 = int(num1)
    intnum2 = int(num2)
    if operator == "+":
        result = intnum1 + intnum2
    elif operator == "-":
        result = intnum1 - intnum2
    elif operator == "*":
        result = intnum1 * intnum2
    elif operator == "/":
        result = intnum1 / intnum2
    else:
        print("Invalid operator")
        return

    print(f"{result:.1f}")

main()
```

I am taking the cs50p course by harvard, and currently on week 1 only. Therefore I am really too new to understand some of your comments. But I am very thankful for the help you guys offered!

Answer (score -2):

here is a possible solution to your problem using regex.

```
 import re
 x = re.findall(r'(\d+)',"1+1 + 1")
 sum = sum([int(y) for y in x])
 sum
```

attaching some useful regex resources :
[cheatsheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/?searched=regular%20expression&advsearch=oneword&highlight=ajaxSearch_highlight%20ajaxSearch_highlight1%20ajaxSearch_highlight2)
[regex101](https://regex101.com/)

EDIT :
as puupuls mentioned, an approach could be to handle multiple signs in the expression using the python eval parser

```
import re
pattern =  r'(\d+[\+\-\*\/]\d+[\+\-\*\/\d\s]*)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)
expression = matches[0].replace(" ", "")
eval(expression)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i77317881/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text.

Comment: This works only if all signs are the same. They should also get a list of operators to correctly interpret equation

Comment: What about floating point values (as input)?

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice! However I am currently a very new self taught coder, I am trying to stick with what the course has taught which doesnt include any of the import of libraries/package yet. But I will definitely look it up soon! Thanks!